# Overriding add cart module

Tags: magento2, module

Trying to create a module that redirects the customer to the account creation page when they add to cart if they are not logged in, I have the following code in app/code/Mason/CheckoutRedirect/Plugin/Checkout/Controller/Cart/Add.php:

```
namespace Mason\CheckoutRedirect\Plugin\Checkout\Controller\Cart;

class Add
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface
     */
    protected $objectManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $url;

    /**
     * Data constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
    ) {
        $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->url = $url;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $contactUrl = $this->url->getUrl('customer/account/create');
        $result = [];
        $result['backUrl'] = $contactUrl;

        $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
            $this->objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data')->jsonEncode($result)
        );
        return;
    }
}
```

All this is doing is returning a JSON object:

{"backUrl":"https://domain.com/customer/account/create/"}

But it isn't redirecting.  I think I might be accidentally over riding the whole class rather than extending it, but I'm not sure what to change to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
class Add
{
    /** @var \Magento\Customer\Model\Session */
    protected $customerSession;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory
     */
    protected $resultRedirectFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface
     */
    protected $urlManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data
     */
    protected $jsonHelper;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $url
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\RedirectFactory $resultRedirectFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\Helper\Data $jsonHelper
    ) {
        $this->customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->resultRedirectFactory = $resultRedirectFactory;
        $this->urlManager = $urlManager;
        $this->jsonHelper = $jsonHelper;
    }

    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {

        if(!$this->customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            if (!$subject->getRequest()->isAjax()) {
                $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
                $resultRedirect->setUrl('customer/account/create');
                return $resultRedirect;
            } else {
                $result = [];
                $result['backUrl'] = $this->urlManager->getUrl('customer/account/create');
                return $subject->getResponse()->representJson(
                    $this->jsonHelper->jsonEncode($result)
                );
            }
        }

        return $proceed();
    }
}
```